# Hibernate Named Query with Join issue

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to create a named query which joins a two tables based on an id. I am getting a HibernateException saying "errors in named queries: Users.getAllUsers

the Users bean has a private Set image variable. The UserImages bean is mapped to a table with the images for all the users. This is my named query.

```
@NamedQueries ({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.getUserImage",
    query("from Users as users INNER JOIN fetch users.image as image WHERE users.userId = image.userId" AND users.userId =: passedId)
})
```

I pass in the variable one as the passedId argument in the named query.

I am pretty new to hibernate but I was told to use the fetch command for this since I have a set within the User bean which holds a bunch of UserImage bean objects. Anyone see why this would not work? The actual SQL query that I am basing this off of which works in my sql editor is

SELECT * FROM users as u WHERE INNER JOIN user_images as images ON users.userId = images.userId AND users.userId = 1;

Comment: Why do you have a userId in the image? Looks as you had foreign keys in your entity model. Why call you the query getUserImage, when it returns users? It smells like fundamental misconceptions about hibernate.

Comment: Apart from this, the colon should be the prefix of passedId `= :passedId` without whitespace. And there is a double quotation mark after userId.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It turned out my query was right the error was that I was not properly passing the parameter from my Dao.